# Hiding dynamic div in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, html

In my `<div>` the id attribute is the dynamic result which is comming from the webpage.
It's like following

```
<div class="row" id="WC_AddressEntryForm<c:out value='_${paramPrefix}'/>_div_firstname">
```

so the `${paramPrefix}` value is changing dynamically.

also the few next `<div>` id is having this type of codes

```
<div class="row" 
id="WC_AddressEntryForm<c:out value='_${paramPrefix}'/>_div_lastname">

<div class="row" id="WC_AddressEntryForm<c:out value='_${paramPrefix}'/>_div_1" >
```

and few more similar to this.
My requirement is to hide the div when ever the `${paramPrefix}` value is **user**
for all those `<div>` previously written
So what is the way to achieve it??

Thanks a lot & 
*Happy new Year*

Comment: Yes i am getting it on page load as per my previous selection on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this JS code on the after the target element code

```
<div class="row" id="WC_AddressEntryForm<c:out value='_${paramPrefix}'/>_div_firstname">

<script>
   document.getElementById('WC_AddressEntryFormuser_div_firstname').style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
```

or if you really want to remove the allocated space of the div you can use the `display` css attribute and set it to `none`

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('WC_AddressEntryFormuser_div_firstname').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

Ok so it seems `_${paramPrefix}` to contain dynamic values well the thing you can do is this

```
<script>
var user = "<c:out value='_${paramPrefix}'/>";
if(user != ""){ //hide when user variable contains something
   document.getElementById('WC_AddressEntryForm'+  user +'_div_firstname').style.display = 'none';
   //you can hide other elements here...
}
</script>
```

well this would change as your requirement changes

Reference: 
http://rakibulislam.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/changing-css-property-using-javascript/

Comment: True......this will work but you have to handle visibility and display on event. On which event are checking '_${paramPrefix}' equals to "User" ?

Comment: OK thats right but thing is that there are several divs which i need to hide.Like in this case ****_div_firstname _div_lastname _street address are there. So how do i hide them at a time??

Comment: so it means the `_${paramPrefix}` is not fixed as `user`?

Comment: I appreciate ur concern Mahan but what about _div_lastname and _div_street_address ?

Comment: well please have time to study the codes. I gonna revise my answer so you can have something to study. Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
  <%   
      if (! paramPrefix.equals("User")) {
  %>
        <div class="row" id="WC_AddressEntryForm<c:out value='_${paramPrefix}'/>_div_firstname">

 <%   } %>
```

Comment: well this is my first idea but if we will make it on the server-side and the user still want to show the div then the user need to create the div using javascript. the user put a tag `javascript` so it's like the OP wants only to hide it using `javascript`